# Prepositions before participle clauses

Tags: prepositions, participles

I am currently studying participle clauses that have adverbial meaning, and was faced with something that I'm having a hard time understanding.

In "Advanced Grammar In Use," the book I'm studying grammar with, prepositions could sometimes be placed before present participle to add additional meaning.
(Ex> Instead of listening to this, I would rather go see a movie)

However, as far as I know, preposition is supposed to be placed right before nouns, thus constituting adverbial phrase with "preposition + noun" structure, and the present participle is usually used as adjective. Therefore, wouldn't it be more natural to consider "instead of" in the example sentence as a preposition and "Listening" as gerund, which is basically a noun derived from verb, thus in turn both as a combination of preposition and a noun?

Is there any grammatical rationale behind explaining "instead of listening" as "preposition + present participle?" or this is just a grammatical exception justified by an effort to categorize them into participle clauses based on a broad meaning?

I'm so dying to find out.
I will be waiting for your insightful answer.

Comment: Nomenclature for the *-ing* form varies from author to author: some distinguish gerunds from participles, others don't. *CGEL* calls it a *gerund-participle*, which is klunky but avoids this particular confusion.

Comment: I don't think you are quoting the right example because "Listening to this, I would rather go see a movie" will never stand as a valid sentence as it doesn't make much sense. You need to take a picture of the particular page and paste it here.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks for your answer. So it's somewhat customary.

Comment: @Rathony Thanks for your comment. However, the exact example sentence that I quoted is "Instead of listening to this, I would rather go see a movie" You must have missed "Instead of"

Comment: Nope, using "Instead of listening to this" is a must. Not *adding additional meaning*.  If you want to ask a question related with grammar, you need to quote at least two or three examples.

Comment: @Rathony You don't seem to understand my question. In the sentence "Instead of listening to this, I would rather go see a movie," the whole "Instead of listening to this" is explained by Advanced Grammar In Use as a "Participle clause" that is used adverbially add additional information to the main clause. And some of the more examples quoted directly from the book are as follows: (1) After spending so much money on the car, I can't afford a holiday (2) Before being changed last year, the speed limit was 70 kph.

Comment: @Rathony So now, what I have understood so far in both cases is that After and Before are preposition after which nouns (in this case, gerunds (~ing)) normally follow. However, the book explains that while Before and After are prepositions, spending and being are not gerunds (noun) but present participle (mostly adjective). Now that I've offered sufficient examples, please answer my questions.

Comment: If you want me to understand the question, just post a few more examples by editing the post or take a picture of the page and post it.

Comment: “Instead” is a preposition in your example, followed by another preposition "of" whose complement is the gerund-participial clause “listening to this”. “Listening” is not a noun, it’s a verb followed by the PP “to this” as complement. The whole PP “instead of listening to this” is functioning as a supplementary adjunct. Btw, I have seen "instead of" called a compound preposition, but there's some doubt about whether that's a good description.